# Infopath 2007: Hide a checkbox control

Tags: sharepoint, checkbox, infopath

I'm developing an infopath 2007 web-form and I'd like to be able to hide a checkbox.  The control doesn't do this inherently, so does anyone have a good method for hiding them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add conditional formating to the checkbox.
Remove the text behind the box (would be visible all time).
Add an expression field behind the checkbox and put your text in here.
Then give that expression box the same conditional fomating.

An alternative:

Put the checkbox into a scetion with conditional formating
(This needs more space but is eaysier to build and manage later.)